# Nextjs 12.2 add custom headers before api route requests runs

Tags: next.js, middleware, request-headers

Is it possible to run a middleware (or any other structure) to set some custom headers to a requisition, before it is sent via api routes?

I'm currently using Next.js 12.2 and have to include some authorization headers to a lot of requests that already exists on the project, but I'm looking to some way to create a helper that can manage adding the headers without having to add it to all the api routes directly.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I handle this situation by implementing a custom `Fetcher` Class and a hook `useRequest` to implement the `Fetcher` Functionality. This makes all API request functionality easier, and also updating any portion is also very easy. Here is my code I hope it will be helpful:

---

#### Fetcher.ts

```js
type Token = string | null | undefined;
type BaseHeader = Object | undefined;
type Url = string;

class Fetcher {
    token: Token = undefined;
    logger: any = console;
    log: boolean = true;
    baseHeader: BaseHeader = {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    constructor(_token: Token = undefined, _log: any = true, _baseHeader: BaseHeader = undefined) {
        if (_token) this.token = _token;
        if (_baseHeader) this.baseHeader = _baseHeader;
        this.log = _log;
    }

    getHeader() {
        return {
            ...this.baseHeader,
            Authorization: this.token && `token ${this.token}`,
        }
    }

    get(_url: Url) {
        return this.fetch_data(_url, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: this.getHeader()
        })
    }

    post(_url: Url, _body: Object) {
        return this.fetch_data(_url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: this.getHeader(),
            body: JSON.stringify(_body),
        })
    }

    put(_url: Url, _body: Object) {
        return this.fetch_data(_url, {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: this.getHeader(),
            body: JSON.stringify(_body),
        })
    }

    patch(_url: Url, _body: Object) {
        return this.fetch_data(_url, {
            method: "PATCH",
            headers: this.getHeader(),
            body: JSON.stringify(_body),
        })
    }

    delete(_url: Url, _body: Object | undefined = undefined) {
        return this.fetch_data(_url, {
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: this.getHeader(),
            body: _body && JSON.stringify(_body),
        })
    }
}

export default Fetcher;
```

---

#### useRequests.ts

This is the hook that utilizes the `Fetcher` Class and takes a token that is stored in the redux if the authenticated is true. In your case, you can take the token from where you stored it, maybe something like local storage.

```js
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {RootState} from "../../redux/reducers";
import getLogger from "../logger/getLogger";
import Fetcher from "./fetcher";

const useRequest = (authenticated = false, _log = true, _token: any = undefined) => {
    if (authenticated && !_token) _token = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth.token);
    const logger = getLogger();
    if (logger.showLog('info') && _log) _log = true;
    return new Fetcher(_token, _log);
};

export default useRequest;
```

No need to provide any header additional header info. The usage will look like this:

```js
const request = useRequest(true);
request.get(REST_API_ENDPOINTS.auth.v1.userInfo()).then((response) => {
                dispatch(userInfoUpdateAction(response));
```

It can be implemented in a more simplified manner, but once you set it, there is no more configuration needed. I prefer a more detail implementation. I hope its helpful to you,